# How to get existing SourceControl via VSCode extension API?

Tags: visual-studio-code, version-control, vscode-extensions

The VSCode extension API provides [a means of creating a new `SourceControl`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#scm). Is there any way to ask for an existing `SourceControl` for the `WorkspaceFolder`? I'd like to be able to learn about scm file status from an extension without having to recreate existing version control plugins; instead, I'd like to be able to asking the existing plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Very late answer by as I had the same question a while ago I thought I should share what I found.

At that time, I was trying to build an extension to get the remote URL for the current file opened in the editor, so I used the default [Git integration for VSCode](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/tree/main/extensions/git) after some research as the documentation doesn't make this very easy to find.

Here's a little snippet of how you can use it to extract information about the current repository:

```
const gitExtension = vscode.extensions.getExtension<GitExtension>('vscode.git').exports;
const git = gitExtension.getAPI(1);

const repository = git.getRepository('current-workspace-path');
const { remotes, HEAD } = repository.state;
for (const remote of remotes) {
  const { fetchUrl } = remote;
}
```

You can get the current workspace path using the workspace (there might be a better way though):

```
const workspaceRootUris = vscode.window.workspaceFolders.map(ws => ws.uri);
```